# Proving if $\sum a_n ^2 < \infty$ then $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was thinking of using Ratio test but I have been unsuccessful so far. It's sufficient for me to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right|$ converges to $l <1$.

By hypothesis, we have that $\sum a_n ^2 < \infty$, hence, $\lim a_n =0$. But $\lim a_n =0$ is a much weaker hypothesis to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ converges to some $l <1$. Because $\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ converges to $0$ but $\frac{1/(n+1)}{1/n}$ converges to $1$.

I don't need solutions, some hints would be enough for me to finish this.

Comment: Is that Cauchy-Schwarz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: from the Cauchy-Schwarz, we have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|\frac{1}{i}\right|^2\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$$